# tcsh display cursor on next line

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I have been trying to get hold of this since many days. Essentially what I need in my tcsh is this

```
[machine_name:current_dir]72 
%
```

instead of

```
[machine_name:current_dir]72 %
```

so that I can always type my commands on the next line.

What have I tried so far?

I have used [this](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php) and [this](http://www.tcsh.org/PromptExamples) as a guidelines to change my .cshrc_mine file. But nothing has worked so far. Would appreciate if anybody could help me with this.

Comment: The first example in this [link](http://www.tcsh.org/PromptExamples) that you provided shows it exactly what you need. Can you paste the configuration what you have done

Comment: setenv PROMPT [%n@%m:%c]%#\n

Comment: @Recker Using `setenv PROMPT` will not work. The page you linked to that says to use it is wrong. Use `set prompt = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tcsh, use this command:

```
set prompt = "[%m:%/]%h\n% "
```

And in Bash:

```
export PS1="[\h:\w]\!\n% "
```

Comment: 72 is just a command history number. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Recker Use `%h` for the history event number.